# Flow Accumulation and Flow Path Error from Flow Direction Raster in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, flow-accumulation, hydrology-toolset

I am trying to generate a flow accumulation and flow length raster from flow direction.

I have successfully generated a flow direction raster from a DEM that was clipped by the 'Clip (Data management tool)'. This was done using the hydrology toolset in spatial analyst tools, in ArcMap 10.2. See image.
[image: Flow direction raster generated from clipped DEM]

When I attempt to generate the flow accumulation or flow length rasters in ArcMap 10.2 I am receiving the following error message:

> 'Output accumulation raster' `<empty>`.

Has anyone had a similar problem and rectified it? Could it be something to do with the way the data has been clipped? I only want to generate flow accumulation and flow lengths for the clipped area.

---

This problem was solved by following the advice of FelixIP 53 in comments.

Comment: Have you populated the 'Output accumulation raster' box? Can you send a shot of the tool in action, your picture is nice but doesn't explain much (no legend). I haven't used Arc Hydro since 8.3 but I can't imagine it's changed that much.

Comment: +1 @Michael for not expecting changes. In fact there is none since arcview 3, or likely it's predecessor

Comment: Set Extent to clipped flow direction, cell size and snap raster. Output to old grid, not fgdb raster

Comment: What was before ArcView 3 @FelixIP? I can only remember ArcINFO (now called workstation) before AV 3.2... those were the days! I didn't use ArcINFO hydro tools - no need, it was as much a pain to use the Forms as to type it all in. It *should* work with any valid raster including fGDB but I've found sticking to the time-tested GRID (as you suggest) and ERDAS Img solves quite a few problems that *shouldn't* occur.

Comment: Thank you, changing the file type of the raster from fGDB worked.

Comment: This problem was solved by following the advice of FelixIP 53 in comments.